# Xcode 8 replaces colorSpace in storyboard files

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode8

when I upgraded to Xcode8, of course it converted the .storyboard files to the newest version.
When I cleaned-rebuilded the application, I noticed that the background color isn't the same as before.
Interesting fact: xcode8 automatically replaces

```
colorSpace="calibratedRGB"
```

to

```
colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"
```

My question: the calibratedRGB is a deprecated thing and I should not use is anymore? Or just apple converted the storyboard badly?

Comment: There are big color management changes in Xcode 8 / iOS 10. You might want to watch the relevant WWDC videos.

Comment: Mine are being changed from calibratedWhite and calibratedRGB to custom/sRGB. I guess that is correct?

Answer (score 6):

I had something similar. The majority of my storyboards were fine. However some colors were wrong.

In the color picker there's a small gear icon in the upper right, which lets you choose a color space. For most this was set to sRGB.

However a few labels had their text color in the "Generic RGB" color space. I can't explain how this happened.

Changing those rogue colors to sRGB corrected their colors.